# how can i give entity name as a variable to a query in spring boot jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@Query("select c from :entity c )

BaseEntity findOne( @Param("value") String entity );
```

this gives an error saying :-

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
>   unexpected token: : near line 1, column 15 [select c from :entity c ]
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions

There is Your answer, including an example.

Edit: This is not 100% what You asked about, but this is only possible way of manipulating entity inside @Query.

Comment: +1 It would better if you post the minimal answer here and link to the documentation for more information.